# Значения одного селекта изменяются в зависимости от выбора другого

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel, select

Столкнулась с небольшой проблемой, суть которой заключается в том, чтобы при выборе значения одного селекта изменялись варианты выбора другого.

Код Контроллера:

```
public function create()
{
    $categories = Category::all();
    $fandoms = Fandom::all();

    return view('story.create', [
        'categories' => $categories,
        'fandoms' => $fandoms
    ]);
}
```

Представление:

```
               <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="category-select" class="col-md-4 col-form-label">Категорія</label>

                    <select id="category-select" class="form-control" name="category-select">
                        <option>Виберіть категорію</option>
                        @foreach ($categories as $category)
                            <option value="{{ $category->id }}">
                                {{ $category->category_name }}
                            </option>
                        @endforeach
                    </select>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="fandom-select" class="col-md-4 col-form-label">Фендом</label>
                    <select id="fandom-select" class="form-control" name="fandom-select" disabled="disabled">
                        <option>Виберіть фендом</option>
                        @foreach ($fandoms as $fandom)
                            @if ($fandom->category_id == 1)
                                <option value="{{ $fandom->id }}">
                                    {{ $fandom->fandom_name }}
                                </option>
                            @endif
                        @endforeach
                    </select>
                </div>
```

Скрипт:

```
<script>
    $('#category-select').change(function() {
        var value = $("#category-select option:selected").val();
        if (value==="Виберіть категорію") {
            $('#fandom-select').prop('disabled', true);
        } else {
            $('#fandom-select').prop('disabled', false);
        }
    });
</script>
```

Результат должен быть таким:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам необходимо выполнять обработку данных со стороны пользователя (через JavaScript) вручную, подгрузив все опции изначально в какую-нибудь переменную. Удобнее было бы использовать какой-либо минимальный JS-фреймворк, того же Alpine.js было бы достаточно, но через jQuery тоже можно. Выглядеть будет примерно так:

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <label for="fandom-select" class="col-md-4 col-form-label">Фендом</label>
    <select id="fandom-select" class="form-control" name="fandom-select" disabled="disabled">
        <option>Виберіть фендом</option>
        <!-- Отсюда убрать список фендомов -->
    </select>
</div>
```

JS:

```
<script>
    // Загрузить список фандомов в переменную
    let fandoms = JSON.parse('@json($fandom)') // array
    $('#category-select').change(function() {
        let value = $("#category-select option:selected").val();
        let $select = $('#fandom-select');

        // Очищаем список текущих фандомов
        $select.empty();

        // Заполняем нужными данными
        $select.append('<option>Виберіть фендом</option>');

        fandoms.filter(fandom => fandom.catefory_id === value)
            .forEach(fandom => {
                $select.append($('<option>', {
                    value: fandom.id,
                    text: fandom.fandom_name
                });
            })

        $select.prop('disabled', value === "Виберіть категорію")
    });
</script>
```